# Check how many days between two dates (fails)

Tags: javascript, date, datediff

This is how I had it done:

```
var sDate = $('.start input').datepicker('getDate').getTime();
var nDate = $('.end input').datepicker('getDate').getTime();            
var dias = Math.floor((nDate - sDate)/1000/60/60/24) + 1;
```

But it fails

`20/03/2014 to 30/03/2014` -> `11` days

and

`21/03/2014 to 31/03/2014` -> `10` days, when the difference is the same,

Where is the flaw?

Comment: `round` instead of `floor`? How about `Math.round(Math.abs((sDate.getTime() - nDate.getTime())/(24*60*60*1000)));`

Comment: It's still 11, http://jsfiddle.net/8BD8A/. I think there's something weird with datepicker('getDate').getTime(), maybe some H:m:s counts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right code is this (as @vinod-gubbala stated above):

```
var dias = Math.round((nDate - sDate)/(1000*60*60*24));
```

Basically, you get the difference in (milliseconds) of the days and divide them by 1000 (to concert  to seconds) * 60 (60 seconds per minute) * 60 (60 minutes per hour) * 24 (24 hours a day).

Don't know why you are adding `+1` at the end. Of course this will work with complete days, I mean, comparing dates with he same time.

The problem you are experiencing could be something with the [daylight saving time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time). Have in mind that for 2014, the last sunday of march (march 30th) there is a time change (at least in Europe), so there is an hour less and your function, as it do a floor, rounds down and you lose a day.

Regards.

Comment: I add +1 because I need the days, not the nights ;) OMG, the time change, I didn't even consider. so round will work in the winter change?

Comment: It must, think that round will go up or down to the nearest integer. You can try with dates containing Oct. 26th 2014 (last october sunday this year).

Answer (score 1):

You have to round instead of floor.

```js
 var oneDay = 24*60*60*1000; // hours*minutes*seconds*milliseconds
 var sDate = $('.start input').datepicker('getDate').getTime();
 var nDate = $('.end input').datepicker('getDate').getTime(); 

 var diffDays = Math.round(Math.abs((nDate - sDate)/(oneDay)));
```

Comment: This seems to work, but my code seemed to work, too. How confident are you with this? can i put it in production environament?

Comment: I am pretty confident on this.

Answer (score 0):

I did this:

```
var d1 = new Date('2013-03-20 00:00:00')
var d2 = new Date('2013-03-30 00:00:00')
(d2.getTime() - d1.getTime()) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24 + 1; //11
```

And then this:

```
var d1 = new Date('2013-03-21 00:00:00')
var d2 = new Date('2013-03-31 00:00:00')
(d2.getTime() - d1.getTime()) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24 + 1; //11
```

So there is no flaw there, most likely it's an error in creation of **Date()** object of the jQuery datepicker. I suggest you do the following:

```
console.log(nDate,sDate);
console.log(((nDate - sDate)/1000/60/60/24)+1);
```

And see what does that give you for both dates. You might spot an error there.

Comment: `getTime()` isn't a function on the calendar but of the javascript `Date` object.

Comment: Yes, as you probably can see in my example but in this case `Date` object is created by the jQuery's datepicker, so there might be an error there.

Comment: @d-kasipovic `datepicker('getDate')` is a function of the calendar and returns a `Date` object. `getTime` is a function of the Date object itself.

Comment: I have edited my post, so it reflects your corrections.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://momentjs.com/

Your code will look like:

```
var a = moment($('.start input').datepicker('getDate').getTime());
var b = moment($('.end input').datepicker('getDate').getTime());
d = a.diff(b, 'days')
```